# SiteUsers.GetByEmail() returns user not found error

Tags: 2010, development, spuser, user-information-list

I have a custom webpart in which I get the SPUser object from email address, see the code below. It was working fine for like an year now , but since yesterday it gives a

> "User cannot be found"

error. There was no change made in the code or anywhere else. And I checked in the User Information List whether those email addresses exists and they do. I do understand what is causing this error.
Any suggestion on were to look is appreciated.

Here is the line that's causing problem now:

```
spUser = spWeb.SiteUsers.GetByEmail(txtEmail.Text);
```

**Update**

I also tried checking through powershell by the following method. In this case I am getting some of the users correctly. but for some other users email addresses I tried, it returns the same

> "user cannot be found" exception.

```
$user = $web.Users.GetByEmail("email@domain.com")
```

Comment: Can you please check the User Exists in Active Directory ? User deleted is not synced with UserInformationList instantly

Comment: @AkarshGupta ... The users are both in AD and in the user info list. And both places have the email address set.

Comment: For your Powershell, to make sure you're comparing apples to apples, make sure you access `$web.SiteUsers` instead of `$web.Users`

Comment: @Thriggle Thanks for that tip but that doesnt solve my issue.

Answer (score 0):

One option may be to replace `spWeb.SiteUsers.GetByEmail` with `spWeb.EnsureUser`.

Even though the documentation indicates that EnsureUser accepts a user's domain\username as a parameter, in practice I've found that an email address works as well, although this may be dependent on your environment's configuration.

Answer (score -1):

kindly try below.

```
spUser = spWeb.AllUsers.GetByEmail(txtEmail.Text);
```